# Can someone please point out any mistake in workflow screenshot?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have implement a workflow which has only one stage. I try to apply some logic through If-else statements which you can see in Screen Shot below. I want to send an email message for this particular addres Agilty@microsoft.com except from this a general email message goes to all members when they will be included in list. But rather than sending specific message to Agilty@microsoft.com the system send the same general message to it. 

Can anyone spot the problem in below logic. 
[image]

Comment: Write CurrentItem:Responsibility to the history log. What does it say? Is it really the same value as the email address?

Comment: Thanks Teylyn and Yes so what is happening here, there are two column name i.e. Raised by and Responsibility both contain the email address of different people. Only for Agilty@microsoft.com I have special message. and for all others email addresses I have different second email message which is in else statement. Agilty@microsoft.cim is also part of the above mentioned columns. Does this answer your question Teylyn? and Can you please bit more explain what do you mean by history log?

Comment: I guess the condition Agilty@microsoft.com = CurrentItem:Responsibilty is returning false hence it is not executing special message. As Teylyn has suggested, print the CurrentItem:Responsibilty value in history log and then check what it is returning.

Comment: You need to learn about the workflow history list. If you want to have a snowflake's chance in hell to debug workflows you need to know how to use it. At the moment you are flying blind and have no idea what your field values are. Use the "log" action from the action menu to write to the history list. In the workflow properties you can see which list is used for the log. Unhide the history list in SPD and open it in the browser to check what the workflow has written.

Answer (score 2):

1. The email address : Agility@microsft.com is missing "o" in word microsoft.
2. Check for equality in text case i.e. CurrentItem:Responsibility might be returning agility@microsoft.com whereas we are comparing to "Agility@microsoft.com" - Difference in alphabet case for "A" in "Agility"